# Combine columns of a dataframe with different delimters

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to combine the columns of a dataframe like the following

```
df['new_col'] = df[df.columns].apply(
        lambda x: ': '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
        axis=1
    )
```

This uses the same delimiter for all columns. But I would like to use different delimiters.

For example, the initial dataframe contains three columns ['id', 'value', 'units']. I would like to use `:` while combining `id` , `value` and space `' '` between `value` and `units`.

Suggestions on how to do this will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you combine it, if only limit columns

```
df['new'] = df['id'].astype(str) + ':' + df.value.astype(str) + ' ' + df.units.astype(str)
```